# Trim/Truncate string to a maximum number of bytes

Tags: vb.net, string, byte, arrays, truncate

I am working with some MP3s in ASP.NET coding in VB and have come across a couple of problems with the ID3 tag length limits.

It seems that most tags have a limit of 30 bytes.

I know how to get the length in bytes of a string, but want to be able to trim a string to a maximum of 30 bytes, minus however many bytes `...` is, so that where needed I can trim a title to "this is part of a title..." where the total is <= 30 bytes.

EDIT:

For clarification;

The titles are string values, that must be <= 30 bytes.

Using [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) I am able to easily convert my string to a byte array:

```
Dim bytes as byte() = "This title".ToAsciiBytes()
```

Then I get the length in bytes:

```
Dim L as integer =  bytes.length()
```

What I need next is to **grab just the first 30 bytes** and convert back to a string (which is simply `bytes.FromAsciiBytes()`)

Comment: It would help if you show some of your code. From your question and the tags you have applied, it is not clear if you have a String, or an array of Byte.

Comment: Well, I can have either! I have a string, I need it to be <= 30 bytes long. Using ServiceStack, I can simply convert the string to a byte array `"this strng"..ToAsciiBytes()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function FormatTitle(ByVal title As String) As String
   Dim byte() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(title)

   If bytes.Length > 30 Then
      Dim dot As Byte = 46 'ascii value of "."
      bytes(27) = dot
      bytes(28) = dot
      bytes(29) = dot
      Array.Resize(bytes, 30)
   End If

   Return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
End Function
```